# Is there a way to easily compare 2 AST structures disregarding position?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to easily compare 2 ast's on babel?

Consider a program like this as the source file:

```js
// example.ts
import { foo } from "bar";

describe("Some test", () => {
  let moduleFixture: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    moduleFixture = await foo.createTestingModule({}).compile();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await foo.tearDown();
  });
});
```

And consider the following babel program

```js
const babelParser = require("@babel/parser");
const { default: traverse } = require("@babel/traverse");
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const recast = require("recast");
const { default: template } = require("@babel/template");

const source = readFileSync(`./example.ts`, "utf-8");

const buildBeforeAll = template(
  `  beforeAll(async () => {
    moduleFixture = await foo.createTestingModule({}).compile();
  });  `,
  {
    plugins: ["typescript"],
  }
);

const beforeAllAst = buildBeforeAll();
const ast = babelParser.parse(source, {
  allowImportExportEverywhere: true,
  plugins: ["typescript"],
});

traverse(ast, {
  enter(path) {
    const isBeforeAll = path.isIdentifier({ name: "beforeAll" });
    if (isBeforeAll) {
      // Somehow compare is beforeAllASt === path
      console.log(`found an appropriate beforeall`);
      path.replaceWithSourceString(`beforeEach`);
    }
  },
});
console.log(recast.print(ast).code);
```

What would be the best way to compare beforeAllAst with a traversed node?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to made such modifications will be using [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer, I'm working on.

[Here is how it looks like](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/e3ecad36548923483318a8d54ea80496/18b4eb5c3a3264f1095cd5f25f7890d0252fa3e1):

```js
const source = `
  beforeAll(async () => {
    moduleFixture = await foo.createTestingModule({}).compile();
});
`;

module.exports.replace = () => ({
    [source]: (vars, path) => {
        path.node.callee.name = 'beforeEach'
        return path;
    },
});
```

This plugin searches for exact mach of `beforeAll` function call. It uses [`@putout/compare`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/compare#readme) which can be used directly in your code:

```js
const {compare} = require('@putout/compare');

traverse(ast, {
  enter(path) {
    const isBeforeAll = path.isIdentifier({ name: "beforeAll" });
    if (compare(path, beforeAllAst)) {
      // Somehow compare is beforeAllASt === path
      console.log(`found an appropriate beforeall`);
      path.replaceWithSourceString(`beforeEach`);
    }
  },
});
```

`@putout/compare` compares AST-node with given string or other AST-node